# A pop up window for OTP verification after submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

So here is my code using ajax to load php and insert values into database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#regBtn').click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url:"register.php",
  type:"POST",
  data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('#RepMsg').fadeIn();
    $('#RepMsg').html('Sending OTP...');
     },
      success:function(response){
   if(response == 1){
    $('#RepMsg').fadeIn();
    $('#RepMsg').html('<i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation" 
   style="color:red; font-size:11px;"></i>This Email is already 
   Taken.')
  }else{ 
    window.location.replace('verify.php');
     }
     }
   })
    });
    });
   </script>
```

So what I want now is to replace that redirect link of verify.php to a pop up menu where I can enter OTP instead of directing it to whole new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a popup on the current page, and remove the

`window.location.replace('verify.php');`

and instead use [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which then communicates to a PHP file via JS ajax taking the OTP, you can simply post the OTP value to PHP file which then prints a response either its validated or not, and then by receiving the response here in JavaScript, you can redirect the user to appropriate page.

Comment: Yes but how to trigger the pop up window to appear just after submitting the form